# SQL aggregate multiple values in a column then Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table with a particular column of products. Let's say product A, B, and C.
This table also has a date column.

I'd like to built a pivot table by month, with columns being combinations of users of these products.

So
Just A
Just B
Just C
A and B
A and C
B and C
A, B and C.

I can do it without the combination values as follows:

```
    Select * from
(Select product_type, date_month, person_id
   From products_table)

PIVOT ( 
   Count(person_id)
   For product_type in 
   (
        [A]
       ,[B]
       ,[C]
   )
) As pivot_table;
```

So my question is, how do I build combinations of these values and then add them to the pivot? Do I need to build the combination columns first and then add them to the pivot somehow?

```
DATE_MONTH | A | B | C | A_B | A_C | B_C | A_B_C

01-01-2020 | 30 |  75 | 10 | 105 | 40 | 85| 115
```

Comment: Could you add sample data and expected result as well!

Comment: *"how do I build combinations of these values and then add them to the pivot"* by not using the restrictive `PIVOT` operator. Instead, use a Cross Tab (aka Conditional Aggregation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this.  First it determines the distinct product types for each person_id.  Then it aggregates the product types using STRING_AGG to create the groupings.  Then it uses conditional aggregation to count the person_id's in each category by month.

Using `STRING_AGG` SQL Server 2017+

```
with
dist_prod_typ_cte(person_id, product_type) as (
    select distinct person_id, product_type 
    from products_table),
prod_grp_cte(person_id, prod_grp) as (
    select person_id, string_agg(product_type, '_') within group (order by product_type) p_type_grp
    from dist_prod_typ_cte
    group by person_id)
select pt.date_month, 
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A' then pt.person_id else null end) A,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='B' then pt.person_id else null end) B,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='C' then pt.person_id else null end) C,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A_B' then pt.person_id else null end) A_B,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A_C' then pt.person_id else null end) A_C,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='B_C' then pt.person_id else null end) B_C,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A_B_C' then pt.person_id else null end) A_B_C
from products_table pt
     join prod_grp_cte pgc on pt.person_id=pgc.person_id
group by pt.date_month;
```

Using `STUFF' and 'FOR XML` SQL Server 2016 and prior

```
with
dist_prod_typ_cte(person_id, product_type) as (
    select distinct person_id, product_type 
    from products_table),
prod_grp_cte(person_id, prod_grp) as (
    select person_id, stuff((select '_' + cast(dptc_in.product_type as varchar(18))
                             from dist_prod_typ_cte dptc_in
                             where dptc.person_id = dptc_in.person_id
                             order by dptc_in.product_type 
                             for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
    from dist_prod_typ_cte
    group by person_id)
select pt.date_month, 
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A' then pt.person_id else null end) A,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='B' then pt.person_id else null end) B,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='C' then pt.person_id else null end) C,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A_B' then pt.person_id else null end) A_B,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A_C' then pt.person_id else null end) A_C,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='B_C' then pt.person_id else null end) B_C,
       count(case when pgc.prod_grp='A_B_C' then pt.person_id else null end) A_B_C
from products_table pt
     join prod_grp_cte pgc on pt.person_id=pgc.person_id
group by pt.date_month;
```

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified, this server isn't on 2017 so there is no STRING_AGG() function. I've seen some posts about using a subquery with XML, but it's an ugly way. Is there something more elegant?

Comment: It's been updated with code for SQL Server 2016 and prior